# ios Changing UIScrollView scrollbar color to different colors

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

How can we change color of UIScrollview's scroll indicator to something like blue, green etc.

I know we can change it to white, black. But other then these colors.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't, of course you can always roll your own. These are your options:

> **UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault:**
>
> The default style of scroll indicator, which is black with a white border. This style is good against any content background.
>
> **UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack:**
>
> A style of indicator which is black and smaller than the default style. This style is good against a white content background.
>
> **UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite:**
>
> A style of indicator is white and smaller than the default style. This style is good against a black content background.

Comment: I have already said in my question that i know we can change to these colors. Anyhow Thanks for your time

Comment: The property for these styles is "indicatorStyle"

Answer (score 18):

Here's more safe **Swift 3** method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let verticalIndicator = scrollView.subviews.last as? UIImageView
    verticalIndicator?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Comment: can we make the scrolling indicator height constant ??
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783442/ios-can-we-make-the-uiscrolling-indicator-height-same-for-any-number-of-data?noredirect=1#comment68790724_40783442

Comment: This is not work

Answer (score 11):

> Both UIScrollView indicator are sub view of UIScrollView. So, we can
>   access subview of UIScrollView and change the property of subview.

**1 .Add UIScrollViewDelegate**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

**2. Add scrollViewDidScroll in implementation section**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
    //get refrence of vertical indicator
    UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
    //set color to vertical indicator
    [verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    //get refrence of horizontal indicator
    UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
    //set color to horizontal indicator
    [horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
```

> Note:- Because these indicator update every time when you scroll
>   (means reset to default). SO, we put this code in scrollViewDidScroll
>   delegate method.

[image]
**[Demo available on GitHub - https://github.com/developerinsider/UIScrollViewIndicatorColor](https://github.com/developerinsider/UIScrollViewIndicatorColor)**

Comment: may be!! not 100% sure. But what is wrong? We put stuff in scroll view indicator without breaking any design guidelines    ....

Comment: Nothing wrong. I just need to know if this won't give me problems when submitting.

Comment: It won't. But it's hacky, so would recommend subclassing scrollview and writing your own tracker indicatorView

Comment: How do you guaranteer that scrollView.subviews.count-1 and scrollView.subviews.count-2 are correct indexes for those indicators?

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski because scroll indicator added as a subview at run times, means when some scroll the scrollview then scrollview add these two scroll indicator as a subview... so scroll indicator always available at last and second last index's when user scrolling

Comment: The code looks like it's setting the vertical background to red and the horizontal to blue.  However, the sample image shows vertical blue and horizontal red.

Comment: This is a terrible idea, as there's no guarantee that the subviews at those indices are the correct indices, or that they even exist. If they don't, you'll get an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski you don't, that's why this is a bad and hacky solution.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the answer of @Alex (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58415249/3876285), I'm posting just a little improvement to change the color of scroll indicators.

```
extension UIScrollView {

    var scrollIndicators: (horizontal: UIView?, vertical: UIView?) {

        guard self.subviews.count >= 2 else {
            return (horizontal: nil, vertical: nil)
        }

        func viewCanBeScrollIndicator(view: UIView) -> Bool {
            let viewClassName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: view))
            if viewClassName == "_UIScrollViewScrollIndicator" || viewClassName == "UIImageView" {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        let horizontalScrollViewIndicatorPosition = self.subviews.count - 2
        let verticalScrollViewIndicatorPosition = self.subviews.count - 1

        var horizontalScrollIndicator: UIView?
        var verticalScrollIndicator: UIView?

        let viewForHorizontalScrollViewIndicator = self.subviews[horizontalScrollViewIndicatorPosition]
        if viewCanBeScrollIndicator(view: viewForHorizontalScrollViewIndicator) {
            horizontalScrollIndicator = viewForHorizontalScrollViewIndicator.subviews[0]
        }

        let viewForVerticalScrollViewIndicator = self.subviews[verticalScrollViewIndicatorPosition]
        if viewCanBeScrollIndicator(view: viewForVerticalScrollViewIndicator) {
            verticalScrollIndicator = viewForVerticalScrollViewIndicator.subviews[0]
        }
        return (horizontal: horizontalScrollIndicator, vertical: verticalScrollIndicator)
    }

}
```

If you don't add `.subviews[0]`, you will get the deeper view and when you try to change the color of the indicator, this will appear with a weird white effect. That's because there is another view in front of it:

[image]

By adding `.subviews[0]` to each indicator view, once you try to change the color by calling:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        scrollView.scrollIndicators.vertical?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourcolor
    }
}
```

You will access to the first view and change the color properly:

[image]

Kudos to @Alex who posted a great solution

Comment: This solution work on ios 14 but not work on ios 12.. It crash

Comment: Weird, it worked for me. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: This works and it's unreal. Xcode 13.2, iOS 15.2

Answer (score 8):

in **IOS 13**

Try this one

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){


        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)].subviews[0]).backgroundColor = UIColor.themeColor(1.0) //verticalIndicator
            (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 2)].subviews[0]).backgroundColor = UIColor.themeColor(1.0) //horizontalIndicator
        } else {
            if let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as? UIImageView) {
                verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.themeColor(1.0)
            }

            if let horizontalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 2)] as? UIImageView) {
                horizontalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.themeColor(1.0)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works on ios 14, but in ios 12 there are two scrollbar

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.0 :**

Add UIScrollView Delegate.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

let horizontalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 2)] as! UIImageView)
horizontalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it would certainly help you

```
    for ( UIView *view in scrollBar.subviews ) {

       if (view.tag == 0 && [view isKindOfClass:UIImageView.class])
       {
        UIImageView *imageView      = (UIImageView *)view;
        imageView.backgroundColor   = [UIColor yellowColor];
       }
    }
```

**Explanation**: UIScrollBar is a collection of subviews. Here scrollBar indicator(vertical/horizontal) is the one of the subviews and it's an UIImageView.So if we set custom color to the UIImageView it effects scrollBar Indicator.

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answer too.

Comment: UIScrollBar is a collection of subviews. Here scrollBar indicator(vertical/horizontal) is the one of the subviews and it's an UIImageView.So if we set custom color to the UIImageView it effects scrollBar Indicator.

Answer (score 2):

You can change an image of indicator, but you should do this repeadeatly

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.chageScrollIndicator()
}

func chageScrollIndicator (){
    if let indicator = self.collection.subviews.last as? UIImageView {
        let edge = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.25,
                                left: 0,
                                bottom: 1.25,
                                right: 0)
        indicator.image = UIImage(named: "ScrollIndicator")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate).resizableImage(withCapInsets: edge)
        indicator.tintColor = UIConfiguration.textColor
    }
}
```

You can use this 2 image as template:
[image: Use this image for @2x]
[image: Use this image for @3x]

Answer (score 2):

in **IOS 13**

Since iOS13 scroll indicators have class _UIScrollViewScrollIndicator, not UIImageView.

Many people used code like

```
let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
```

It's not good idea, because they promised that last subview will be UIImageView :). Now it's not and they can get crash.

You can try following code to get scrollView indicators:

```
extension UIScrollView {

    var scrollIndicators: (horizontal: UIView?, vertical: UIView?) {

        guard self.subviews.count >= 2 else {
            return (horizontal: nil, vertical: nil)
        }

        func viewCanBeScrollIndicator(view: UIView) -> Bool {
            let viewClassName = NSStringFromClass(type(of: view))
            if viewClassName == "_UIScrollViewScrollIndicator" || viewClassName == "UIImageView" {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }

        let horizontalScrollViewIndicatorPosition = self.subviews.count - 2
        let verticalScrollViewIndicatorPosition = self.subviews.count - 1

        var horizontalScrollIndicator: UIView?
        var verticalScrollIndicator: UIView?

        let viewForHorizontalScrollViewIndicator = self.subviews[horizontalScrollViewIndicatorPosition]
        if viewCanBeScrollIndicator(view: viewForHorizontalScrollViewIndicator) {
            horizontalScrollIndicator = viewForHorizontalScrollViewIndicator
        }

        let viewForVerticalScrollViewIndicator = self.subviews[verticalScrollViewIndicatorPosition]
        if viewCanBeScrollIndicator(view: viewForVerticalScrollViewIndicator) {
            verticalScrollIndicator = viewForVerticalScrollViewIndicator
        }
        return (horizontal: horizontalScrollIndicator, vertical: verticalScrollIndicator)
    }

}
```

If you need only one (h or v indicator) - it's better to cut this func and keep only one you need (to improve perfomance).

Also it would be good to call update func inside of DispatchQueue, to keep smoothness of scrolling.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async {
       scrollView.updateCustomScrollIndicatorView()
   }
}
```

Comment: not working. scrollview has empty subviews array :(

Comment: turn on Show Horizontal Indicator, or/and Show Vertical Indicator? @SerjRubens

Comment: it is turned on @Alex

Comment: and scrollview has empty subviews array even without this check ^^^. Just scrollView.subviews.count == 0? (Sure, before you add something on it)

Comment: in the end its not UIScrollView but UITableView. but UITableView is inherited from UIScrollView, so I expected it gonna work the same way. well and yes, I don't add anything on it, but cells could be already initialised and count as subviews. Didn't know that it's so important (-_-) @Alex

Comment: ok, maybe after init subviews count can be 0. But later, when you scroll table view - scroll (table) view should have. So, even after scrolling this method doesn't find scroll indicators?
Have you tried just with scroll view, not table?

Comment: This is the only solution that (almost) worked fine for me, thanks @Alex! I would just add `.subviews[0]` to each indicator view in order to change the color of the first layer instead of the deeper layer. Will post a new answer based on yours 

Answer (score 1):

**This is how the color of the scroll bar is changed:**

```
    //scroll view  
    UIScrollView *scView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];  
    scView.frame = self.view.bounds; //scroll view occupies full parent views  
    scView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 800);  
    scView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];  
    scView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;  
    scView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;  
    scView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;  
    scView.scrollEnabled = YES;  
    [self.view addSubview: scView];
```

Comment: Please improve the [formatting of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) you posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to add image as well, here is the code for Swift 3

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let verticalIndicator = scrollView.subviews.last as? UIImageView
    verticalIndicator?.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
}
```

This works for UITableView and UICollectionView as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article about this not so far ago. Unfortunately color of this bars defined by pre-defined images, so if you are going to change the color of bars some extra work will be required. Take a look to following link, you will definitely find an answer here since I tried to solve the same issue.

http://leonov.co/2011/04/uiscrollviews-scrollbars-customization/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently so I decided to write a category for it.

https://github.com/stefanceriu/UIScrollView-ScrollerAdditions

```
[someScrollView setVerticalScrollerTintColor:someColor]; 
[someScrollView setHorizontalScrollerTintColor:someColor];`
```

It blends it with the original image so only the color will change. On the other hand, it can also be modified to provide a custom image for the scrollers to use.

Comment: I'm confused, what is the purpose of the library if you say it shouldn't be used in production code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in Swift 4, similar to previous answers. In my case I'm recoloring the image to be invisible, set correct corner radius and only execute this process once.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let color = UIColor.red
    guard
        let verticalIndicator = scrollView.subviews.last as? UIImageView,
        verticalIndicator.backgroundColor != color,
        verticalIndicator.image?.renderingMode != .alwaysTemplate
    else { return }
    verticalIndicator.layer.masksToBounds = true
    verticalIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = verticalIndicator.frame.width / 2
    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = color
    verticalIndicator.image = verticalIndicator.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    verticalIndicator.tintColor = .clear
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please use below code on iOS Renderer

```
 private bool _layouted;
 public override void LayoutSubviews()
 {
       base.LayoutSubviews();
       if (!_layouted)
       {
            this.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Red.CGColor;
            var Verticalbar = (UIImageView)this.Subviews[this.Subviews.Length - 1];

            Verticalbar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0099ff").ToUIColor();
            var Horizontlebar = (UIImageView)this.Subviews[this.Subviews.Length - 2];

            Horizontlebar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0099ff").ToUIColor();
            _layouted = true;
       }
}
```

Comment: Added to the code, it's always good to explain why this solves the problem that the question had posed. It'd be ideal to edit this post to include a detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

As for iOS 13 subviews changed so adding simple if, solved this issues.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 13.0) {
    UIView *verticalIndicator = [scrollView.subviews lastObject];
    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
} else {
    UIImageView *verticalIndicator = [scrollView.subviews lastObject];
    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use custom UIScrollView scrollBars to implement color in scrollbars. For more details look [here](http://leonov.co/2011/04/uiscrollviews-scrollbars-customization/)