# Move Image In ScrollView along scrollbar

Tags: ios, uiimageview, scrollbar, scrollview, frame

I want to move UIImageview along scrollbar in scrollview . I tried in DidScroll Delegate

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    static NSInteger previousPage = 0;
    NSLog(@"scrolliview= %f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);

   [_img_moving setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    _img_moving.frame = CGRectMake(
                                 scrollView.contentOffset.x,
                                 0, 320/2, 10);

}
```

frame of uiimageview is not changing.
**Note**: My aim is to make scrollbar of green color  with width 10 px

Comment: what is contentOffset you set for scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, change colours of vertical and horizontal scrollbar according to your need, for more detailed answers please follow this link:
 [ios Changing UIScrollView scrollbar color to different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005187/ios-changing-uiscrollview-scrollbar-color-to-different-colors)

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //get refrence of vertical indicator
    UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
    //set color to vertical indicator
    [verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];


    //get refrence of horizontal indicator
    UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
    //set color to horizontal indicator
    [horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: bro , I had tried that link already but  got no succes , it just change the color of image nor move the image, I want to move the image like scrollbar