# How do I change the colour of scroll bar Indicator in UICollectionView apart from Default,Black or White?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, scrollbar

I want to change the color of horizontal scroll bar **Indicator** of UICollectionView, Apart from default, black or white which could be done in storyboard?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005187/ios-changing-uiscrollview-scrollbar-color-to-different-colors

Comment: Please specify the language in which you wanted to use i.e swift or objective C . I saw somebody answered but they have the confusion. So please write whole content for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate method : 'scrollViewDidScroll'
and add

//get refrence of vertical indicator

```
UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
//set color to vertical indicator
[verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];


//get refrence of horizontal indicator

UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
//set color to horizontal indicator
[horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below code for the Scrolling UICollection View Horizontal Bar color change also refer below link for more information and download sample code from that.

http://blog.mosheberman.com/coloring-the-ios-uiscrollviewindicators/

```
func setScrollIndicatorColor(color: UIColor) {

            for view in self.tableView.subviews {
                if view.isKindOfClass(UIImageView.self),
                    let imageView = view as? UIImageView,
                    let image = imageView.image  {

                    imageView.tintColor = color
                    imageView.image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
                }
            }

            self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()
        }
```

Comment: asfmi - your answer is fine , but the questioner needs the answer in objective C

Comment: Getting Error in Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'isKindOfClass'

Comment: How can call this func for collectionView horizontal scroll color ?