# How to change UIScrollView Indicator color?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift3, uicolor

When I use **UIColor.blue** its changing, but when I try to apply RGB, its not reflected in scrollview indicator.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
    verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 138/255, blue: 252/255, alpha: 1)
//        verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think problem is here

```
verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 138/255, blue: 252/255, alpha: 1)
```

Change to

```
verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 211/255.0, green: 138/255.0, blue: 252/255.0, alpha: 1).
```

The result of division 211/255 is type of integer so it return only 0 or 1 (in this case i think it is 0).

Answer (score 1):

When using RGB values set out UIColor like this

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: <#T##CGFloat#>, green: <#T##CGFloat#>, blue: <#T##CGFloat#>, alpha: <#T##CGFloat#>)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Both UIScrollView indicator are sub view of UIScrollView. So, we can access subview of UIScrollView and change the property of subview.

## 1 .Add UIScrollViewDelegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end
```

## 2. Add scrollViewDidScroll in implementation section

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
 {
     //get refrence of vertical indicator
       UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
    //set color to vertical indicator
      [verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

   //get refrence of horizontal indicator
     UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
  //set color to horizontal indicator
     [horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
 }
```

> Note:- Because these indicator update every time when you scroll (means reset to default). SO, we put this code in scrollViewDidScroll delegate method.

### For Swift

> Add UIScrollView Delegate.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){
   let verticalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 1)] as! UIImageView)
   verticalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

   let horizontalIndicator: UIImageView = (scrollView.subviews[(scrollView.subviews.count - 2)] as! UIImageView)
   horizontalIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

Comment: My problem is not simply changing the color its all about using RGB values

Comment: and get crash on iOS13 for swift version ((. Updated solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58415249/2510002

Answer (score 0):

You should also add this line in order to achieve the exact color you want:

```
verticalIndicator.image = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for changing scrollIndicator of tableView

```
    if let indicatorView = self.tableView.subviews.first(where: { $0.bounds.size.width <= 10 }) {
        indicatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "5A2A7F")
    }
```