# How to change SwiftUI ScrollView Indicator Color

Tags: scrollview, swiftui

The title pretty much says it all. I have a scroll view and I want to change the little line on the right side that shows how far down you are to be yellow. Is there a way to do it in SwiftUI? The only method I can find is `showIndicators`, nothing about changing the color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need yo make your own SwiftUI ScrollView implementation or you would need to use an `UIScrollView` control with a `UIViewRepresentable`.

I have seen this tutorial how to implement a custom [ScrollView with SwiftUI](https://blog.process-one.net/writing-a-custom-scroll-view-with-swiftui-in-a-chat-application/).

If you go with the UIViewRepresentable you can use the standard possibilities you would use for UIScrollView customisations [How to change UIScrollView Indicator color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484070/how-to-change-uiscrollview-indicator-color/40484358).