# How do I create a Shazam-like scrollbar in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Do any of you know how I can create this Shazam scrollbar?

You can slide this circle up and down to scroll the TableView.

I would be happy, thank you!

[--> Here is an example <--](https://i.ibb.co/dB4yv0G/Screenshot-3.png)

Comment: It’s best to ask a more focused question where you tell us what you have done so far and which part you are stuck on

Comment: The code in this project might help. https://github.com/litl/WKVerticalScrollBar

Comment: You can use this third-party for this feature. https://github.com/frichti/FastScroll

Comment: Thanks @vipulthummar! The answer was very helpful

Answer (score -1):

You will have to implement your own moveable view to use as the slider, track its vertical position and change scroll view position based on that. Start from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484070/how-to-change-uiscrollview-indicator-color/40484358) and [this](https://www.process-one.net/blog/writing-a-custom-scroll-view-with-swiftui-in-a-chat-application/) and go from there