# iOS - Can we make the UIScrolling indicator height same for any number of data?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I notice when we have less number of data in tableview scrolling indicator is big as shown in Image1.

But as the number of data in the tableview increases the tableview scrolling indicator size decreases as in Image2.

[image: Image1]
Fig: Image 1

[image: Image2]
Fig: Image 2

**Problem:**
Can we make this scrolling indicator size constant for any number of data ?

Comment: It cannot be done. scrolling indicator size controlled by tableview itself.

Comment: @Poles is there really no way to fix this

Comment: Not in my knowledge.

Comment: @BikramThapa You can hide the scroll bar and implement a custom one if needed. But as Poles mentioned not sure if  there is a straight forward way of controlling the indicator size.

Comment: @GoodSp33d any quick reliable links for custom one

Comment: Here is a link [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005187/ios-changing-uiscrollview-scrollbar-color-to-different-colors), that can be handle indicator, I am not Sure,But It may be helped you.